# Is it possible to create a hash made from other colum values at data input and store it together?

Tags: mysql

For example the data inputted might be `name` , `home_address` and `hash` as

```
+--+----+---------+-----------------------------------------+
|id|name|phone    |hash                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |Joe |123123123|dfaf41c21afbe359228c5a0ed1095b30ff4f50ac |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|2 |Doe |123123332|0fd7083d2af4624c531e8fc937d7a9c945f7ef32 |
+--+----+---------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible when inputting a record generate the hash of the two (`name` and `phone`) and store as the hash value on the hash column using just `mySQL`?

I could script this behavior but I'm wondering if it is possible to do so on mySQL.

Any kind of help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in MySQL function `SHA1()` returns a 40 digit hexadecimal hash:

```
SELECT SHA1('mystring');
```

Output:

`9ce3ea4d6fac2165933b3971e6d5a13753c7d878`

You could concatenate your values like this:

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT(name, phone));
```

When inserting:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, phone, hash)
VALUES ('Joe', '123123123', SHA1(CONCAT('Joe', '123123123')));
```

To update all rows:

```
UPDATE table1
SET hash = SHA1(CONCAT(name, phone));
```

Hint: If you are storing the value in its hexadecimal representation, choose a single byte character set like `ascii`, especially if you plan on indexing the column. `utf8` indexes are 3 times the size. Also, hash algorithms such as SHA1 always output a hash of the same length, so consider using a `CHAR` column instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this behavior for all input on the table ? Without specifying this on all inserts

Comment: Yes, you can create an `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: I don't understand "if I index the hash column I would need to insert it together". What's the issue?